# Safari width issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari, width

Is there a way to fix what Safari is doing to the videos of my web page (shown on the picture below)? It works fine in chrome..I've tried many different "solutions" without success. I think the problem is the width, but i cant find a way to make those videos fit in iphones.

[image: example]

```css
/* -----TRABAJOS----- */
.row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.trabajo-video {
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  flex: 0 1;
}

.trabajo-video iframe {
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.trabajo-video iframe:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .trabajo-video {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .trabajo-video iframe {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 95vw;
  }
}
```

```html
 <section class="section-trabajos js--section-trabajos" id="trabajos">
            <div class="row1">
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/394267911?h=d0dc5419b7" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/601058658?h=ca99e9cfff" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/554312785?h=d02669a5e8" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/548861510?h=79744afee2" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/611892549?h=a8c3f6376d" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/507199207?h=44dc935b21" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/626691091?h=2ca8780c56" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/275921049?h=fff1d08a02" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="trabajo-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/507209760?h=99b7a40f5a" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>  
        </section>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I edited your question to move the CSS to code blocks so it's easier to read. I'm not sure what was going on with the comments in the `.row1` rule block. Could you please make sure my edit matches your intention? There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71603623/edit) link below your question if you would like to make changes.

Comment: Hi! yes it does, thanks! i'm new at this, so any help is welcome!!

Comment: please use the code snippet tool to provide a working example of your code to receive more detailed help

Comment: sorry, i'm new at this, it's there now, hope someone can help!